# ¿Cómo puedo ver los métodos que tiene una determinada clase en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy explorando JavaScript, viniendo de Java, y me encuentro con algo curioso: la documentación no es como estaba acostumbrado. Quisiera conocer, en este caso, los métodos que pueda tener un objeto "socket", o los que pueda tener la ¿clase? "net", pero, no sé si estoy preguntando mal o qué sucede pero no me aparece lo que quisiera. ¿Existe alguna forma específica de hacerlo?

En el siguiente ejemplo se puede ver un pequeño código en JavaScript del que se importa una clase "Server" de  "net"

```js
const { Server } = require('net');

const server = new Server();

server.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`New conecction from ${socket.remoteAddress}:${socket.remotePort}`)
    socket.on("data", (data))
});

server.listen({ port: 8000, host: '0.0.0.0' }, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 8000');
});
```

Comment: Lo que yo hago es ir a la documentación oficial de cada paquete, Javascript trae algunas clases (Objetos) pero son pocas. Lo que hacemos es ir instalando paquetes para no reinventar la rueda. O en muchas ocasiones librerias o frameworks y ahí es donde te digo que vamos a la documentación oficial de cada paquete, libreria o framework. Lo basico de Javascript lo encuentras en [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/) o los editores de codigo te ayudan.

Comment: Entiendo completamente ese sentimiento. La documentación en javascript no suele ser tan técnica como la de java y a veces eso es algo que puede jugar muy en contra. De cualquier manera la referencia fundamental sobretodo si se trata de navegadores es mdn. De hecho, en la barra lateral izquierda te van a salir todos los métodos de la clase, las propiedades, eventos, etc. Por ejemplo, checa [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

Comment: He estado viendo y sigo un poco perdido. En el ejemplo que he estado siguiendo, usan una clase "Server" de "net". No sé si eso es de Node, o  de Js, o de qué, pero no encuentro qué métodos pueda usar, en ninguna de las documentaciones que me mencionaron. ¿Me podrías echar una mano?

Comment: ¿De dónde lo importan? Tal vez si agregaras un fragmento de código pudieras tener más ayuda.

Comment: Tienes razón, discúlpame. Acabo de editar la publicación adjuntando el código en cuestión.

Comment: @DanielSanchez hubieras empezado por ahí. Adjuntar todos los detalles que puedas a tu pregunta es la única forma de garantizar que pueda ser respondida. Estás usando JS pero con node, entonces la cosa cambia, la referencia por defecto es es la [documentación oficial de node](https://nodejs.org/api/documentation.html), en este caso, en el [paquete net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) la clase [Server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#class-netserver).

Answer (score 3):

Con Object.getPrototypeOf() se pueden obtener los métodos de un objeto.

```
const employees = ['Ron', 'April', 'Andy', 'Leslie'];

Object.getPrototypeOf(employees);
```